# Como fazer uma operação usando o TIPO de variável CHAR?

Tags: c, char

Seguem dois códigos.

- O primeiro faz a operação desejada com `if` e `else`.
- O segundo (o qual estou com a dúvida) eu tento reconhecer o `char` digitado, como um operador para daí efetuar a operação.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char operador = ' ';
    float valor1, valor2;
    printf("Entre com um tipo de operacao a ser realizada (+,-,*,/),o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
    scanf("%c %f %f", &operador, &valor1, &valor2);
        if (operador == '+'){
        printf("Resultado da soma %.2f", valor1+valor2);
    }
        else if (operador =='-'){
        printf("Resultado da subtracao %.2f", valor1-valor2);
    }
        else if (operador =='*'){
        printf("Resultado da multiplicacao %.2f", valor1*valor2);
    }
        else{
        printf("Resultado da divisao %.2f", valor1/valor2);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    system ("pause");
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    char operador = ' ';
    float x, y,op,operacao;
    //op=operador
    printf("Entre com um tipo de operacao a ser realizada (+,-,*,/),o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
    scanf("%c %f %f", &op, &x, &y);
    operação= x 'CHAR' y;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente não há forma de fazer isso que você quer em C, como observado nas respostas [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114433/convert-character-into-arithmetic-operator-without-using-switch-case-i-e-conve).
Você pode fazer isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char op;
    float x, y;
    //op=operador
    printf("Entre com um tipo de operacao a ser realizada (+,-,*,/),o primeiro valor e o segundo valor\n");
    scanf("%c %f %f", &op, &x, &y);
    float opc = (op=='+')?(x+y):((op=='-')?(x-y):((op=='*')?(x*y):0));
    printf("%f\n", opc);
}
```

A explicação do trecho de código também está no link acima.

Comment: Eu imaginei fazer o compila, reconhecer que é um operador, mas tabom valeuu